# DOJO giving Error : uncaught reference error dojo is not defined

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am doing a simple project on dijit.Tree.whenever I run the program it is giving below error

```
uncaught reference error:  dojo is not defined
```

and sometimes

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Desktop/dojoapps/dojo/dojo/main.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many Questions on this error.Today I got the same error and resolved within seconds.so,I am giving the solution here :

It is just because your path is incorrect and it is not mapping to dojo.js

First step is,make sure that your path to dojo folder is correct.

And Also,Even if you Map correctly you will see the below error in chrome.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Desktop/dojoapps/dojo/dojo/main.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

The simple solution is,run your code with any server like Apache Tomcat and replace your path with in your code with `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: that's right. also, another solution is to remove the protocol relative URLs if you run it from file system, as it prepends the "file:///" to any protocol relative path.